# Passing props to single-file components in Vue

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js

I'm trying to pass data from my existing app to a single-file component in Vue. However, the component doesn't seem to be receiving the prop from the parent.

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0o0l46xmkw)

Code:

```
// index.js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: "<App/>",
  propsData: {
    someProp: "this is a prop test!!"
  },
  components: { App }
});
```

And the component:

```
// App.js
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>My Todo App! the prop: {{ someProp }}</h1>
        <TodoList/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList.vue";

export default {
  props: ["someProp"],
  components: {
    TodoList
  }
};
</script>
```

The result doesn't show the prop at all, as if it's not passing anything. What gives?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `propsData`; it's primarily intended for testing. Also, you have to actually pass the prop to `App`. Here is your [sandbox updated](https://codesandbox.io/s/0p10qww51l).

Comment: @Bert thank you for the help, I admit I'm not so great at Vue. Quick question though, your example works with the template option - and suppose I'm using a build without the template engine?

Comment: I updated the sandbox to use a render function instead of a template.

Comment: @Bert you have a correct answer, may be you can answer and get points? :)